# Customer Not Notified

Tags: magento-1.9, email, sales

I am not sure if what I see in admin it is right. I mean, why shouldn't be there customer notified status? This is the first time I am using Authorize and I don't have any idea if it related to this. The thing is that I am expecting to see that the customer was notified. Ignore Transaction ID "0" for test purpose because the same happens on live.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those status are set internally by the payment api, therefore there is not need to  notify the customer.

After the payment has been approved, then status that you should pay attention to if you want to know if a order confirmation was send is (upper left hand box)

> Order # 10151xxxx (the order confirmation email was sent)

or

> Order # 10151xxxx (the order confirmation email is not sent)

To view payment status take a look at

Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet

```
protected function _place(
protected function _addTransaction()
```

Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment

```
public function place()
 ...

    // add message to history if order state already declared
    elseif ($order->getState() && ($orderStatus !== $order->getStatus() || $message)) {
        $order->setState($orderState, $orderStatus, $message, $isCustomerNotified);
    }
    // set order state
    elseif (($order->getState() != $orderState) || ($order->getStatus() != $orderStatus) || $message) {
        $order->setState($orderState, $orderStatus, $message, $isCustomerNotified);
    }
```

Comment: OK...so as expected it is fine. In my case the client doesn't update any order..so all the orders are still in processing and the customer wasn't been notified about nothing regarding the status of order. I think here is the problem :)
I saw that 
"Order # 100000147 (the order confirmation email was sent)"